# How to take an input from a user using an entry box in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have used `webbrowser.open()` in my program. I want to take the `input(link)` from the user using an entry box. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. You can use tkinter. As written your question is too broad. Is there a specific part of the problem you are struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the string from a entry box as a variable you need to do this:

Simple script to display the value of an entry box on button click.

```
from Tkinter import *
def getvalue():
    e1_var.get()
    l1 = Label(root, text=e1_var).grid()

root = Tk()
e1_var = StringVar
e1 = Entry(root, textvariable=e1_var).grid()
b1 = Button(root, command=getvalue).grid()
root.mainloop()
```